# Want to import a map of US to excel VBA program and color-code it using excel data

Tags: excel, vba

I have data that corresponds to a particular characteristic for each state in the US. I wrote a quick vba script that color codes each cell based on the cell's value (see below). What I want to do is to color-code a map in the same way.

**Example Data:**

```
Red: >30% - Massachusetts, California, New York, Georgia...
Orange: >20% - Nebraska, Utah, South Dakota...
Yellow: >10% - Michigan, Minnesota....
White: >5% - Florida, Connecticut...
Gray: >1% - Colorado, Montana..
```

So I want to make a map that colors in all of the states with >30% red, >20% orange, > 10%

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Use the Google Chart API: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Answer (score 0):

older versions of excel actually made this very easy (below version 2002)

for newer versions i would just recommend using google charting apis instead, its much easier

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#Example

if you do have a copy of an old excel just insert and then map and you excel will recognise the states etc.

Im not sure why this feature was taken out